# how to get x y position of a window in gxt

Tags: java, gwt, window, gxt

How to get X Y position of a window in GXT? I am able to set the position using setPosition. But I am not able to get the position as there is not get method. Can you please help me in retrieving the position of a window?

```
Window window = new Window();
window.setClosable(true);
window.setWidth(300);
window.setHeight(300);
window.setPosition(30, 50);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get, as for every element in GWT, the element's position with:

```
/**
 * Gets the object's absolute left position in pixels, as measured from the
 * browser window's client area.
 * 
 * @return the object's absolute left position
 */
window.getAbsoluteLeft();
```

and

```
/**
 * Gets the object's absolute top position in pixels, as measured from the
 * browser window's client area.
 * 
 * @return the object's absolute top position
 */
window.getAbsoluteTop();
```

Both methods are part of the UiObject class in GWT, which every widget in GWT 2 inherits.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I am always getting 0 for getAbsoluteLeft() and getAbsoluteTop()

Comment: The widget must be attached to the DOM to get it's position.